# Keeping folder of files in sync over 3 machines

Tags: linux, filesystems, synchronization

Morning,

Got 3 machines that have user content on them, which I need to keep in sync.
This is a 3 way sync.

Currently I run rsync but we just don't handle deletes.
Have looked at something like gluster, but that seems a little over the top

Any other software out there to do a 3 way sync, or a good network file system...? There is for web servers so we don't want a slow / IO hungry process.

3 servers... user content could be added to 1 and needs to be moved to other two.

Comment: What's wrong with rsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about DropBox? I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: this was the first thing that came to my mind when i read the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Use NFS if the machines are on the same network.

Otherwise, use version control software like Git or better yet, Subversion. You'll have to make some scripts to push the changes around. A plus, version control!

Answer (score 0):

If you really think that a distributed filesystem (which is in fact what you need and there are some lighter ones that you could use, such as [XtreemFS](http://www.xtreemfs.org/)) is an overkill for you, then try something like [Aspera](http://asperasoft.com/rsync-replacement/).

Answer (score 0):

GlusterFS is not that hard to set up. If you're using configuration management on those servers (you ARE using CM tools, right?), it should be trivial to set up the servers, set up the volume, install the clients and mount it on every box.